# Column headers not rendering as expected after refactoring <Column />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, primereact

This renders the header properly in that I can see a table with a "Product ID" header for the column:

```
// DataTable.tsx
// React Imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// PrimeReact Imports
import { DataTable as DT } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

// Custom Imports
import DataTableHeader from './DataTableHeader';

const DataTable = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  return (
    <DT
      value={rowData}
      emptyMessage='Run the utility first.'
      size='small'
    >
      <Column field='product_id' header='Product ID' />
    </DT>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

I'm trying to refactor it so I can reuse `<DataTable />` and `<Column />` given they are almost identical throughout the app:

```
// DataTable.tsx
// React Imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// PrimeReact Imports
import { DataTable as DT } from 'primereact/datatable';

// Custom Imports
import DataTableHeader from './DataTableHeader';
import ColumnProductID from './ColumnProductID';

const DataTable = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  return (
    <DT
      value={rowData}
      emptyMessage='Run the utility first.'
      size='small'
    >
      <ColumnProductID />
    </DT>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

```
// ColumnProductID.tsx

import React from 'react';

// PrimeReact Imports
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

const ColumnProductID = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <Column field='product_id' header='Product ID' />
};

export default ColumnProductID;
```

In this case, the `<Column />` header is not rendered... inspecting the page elements for an occurrence of "Product ID" does not yield anything so it seems the `<ColumnProductID />` is not being rendered.

**Suggestions for what I am doing wrong here?**

---

I did manage to get this to work, by doing:

```
// DataTable.tsx
// React Imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// PrimeReact Imports
import { DataTable as DT } from 'primereact/datatable';

// Custom Imports
import DataTableHeader from './DataTableHeader';
import ColumnProductID from './ColumnProductID';

const DataTable = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  return (
    <DT
      value={rowData}
      emptyMessage='Run the utility first.'
      size='small'
    >
      <ColumnProductID field='product_id' header='Product ID' />
    </DT>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

```
// ColumnProductID.tsx

import React from 'react';

// PrimeReact Imports
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

interface ColumnProductIDProps {
  field: string;
  header: string;
}

const ColumnProductID = (props: ColumnProductIDProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <Column field={field} header={header} />
};

export default ColumnProductID;
```

But this is undesirable... in fact it is the very thing I'm trying to avoid and it is pointless to refactor `<Column />` from `primereact` into a `<ColumnProductID />` component. This effectively makes `<ColumnProductID /> === <Column />` with an additional layer and unnecessary complexity.

The redundancy I'm trying to get around is this:

- A field named `status`, for example, can relate to all kinds of data: Customers, Companies, Products, Leads, etc. etc. etc.
- Whatever `<DataTable />` this field `status` appears in, it should have the exact same props.
- If there are `<DataTable />` for Customers, Companies, Products, Leads, and this `<Column field='status' />` is in all of them, and you want to change something about it, then you have to go into each  `<DataTable />` and update it.
- But if you can make a `<ColumnStatus />` component and pass that into the `<DataTable />` then you only need to update it one place: in the `<ColumnStatus />` component.

Comment: Why don't you pass the "field" and "header" props in the DataTable component as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with PrimeReact.  Column is not a a "component" that renders itself so it cannot be wrapped or extended.  The Datatable looks specifically for `<Column>` as children and not anything else.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2268

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2052#issuecomment-1173678665